# Strange middle page with JS code that injects a cookie

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies, system-administration

I have been seeing a strange behaviour in my app these days. Randomly, when I try to fetch a JSON feed from a Ruby on Rails API, I get a response like this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name) { // Local function for getting a cookie value
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start!=-1) {
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length + 1;
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);

        if (c_end==-1) 
            c_end = document.cookie.length;

        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) { // Local function for setting a value of a cookie
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/";
}
function getHostUri() {
    var loc = document.location;
    return loc.toString();
}
setCookie('YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666', 'xxx.yyy.zzz.xxx', 10);
try {  
    location.reload(true);  
} catch (err1) {  
    try {  
        location.reload();  
    } catch (err2) {  
        location.href = getHostUri();  
    }  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

where `xxx.yyy.zzz.xxx` is my public IP address.

I have already searched on Internet and found very few information (people asking about this behaviour and some people giving workarounds, without explaining where this came from).

I suppose that it doesn't come from webapp level, since this occurs in PHP, ASP.net and Rails apps, so I think it could be the webserver, some cache, maybe some Amazon stuff... I don't really know.

At the moment I realised that the examples found were all with NGiNX, but it's source code and docs don't appear to include anything like this.

It appears to be random in my app, while in other don't.

If you want to try it live, you can access to `https://www.manototv.com/` **without JavaScript and in private browsing mode**, you will see that this strange page appears.

Not that the cookie key, `YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666`, is the same all the time and in all apps.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.